# Disabling package configuration warnings (Debian)

Tags: linux, installation, package-management

I installed a package but had a problem during the configuration stage. I manually fixed the issue but every time I use Aptitude it complains about the issue as if it is still present. The installed software works just fine after my intervention. How do I make Aptitude understand that the package is fine and that it can drop the warnings?

Answer (score 0):

I just modified the .postinst file for the package directly. That way it doesn't fail when Aptitude runs it the next time and the package warning is cleared and never seen again.

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question, but can you elaborate on this?  For others with a similar problem, this won't provide much of a solution.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)